# what is the meaning of 'three parts' in :"if ever a man was three parts mad with terror, that man's name is Pinner"?

Tags: expressions, literature

I am quoting from *The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes, The Stockbroker's Clerk by Arthur Conan Doyle*: "There is something which I don't understand in his manner. If ever a man was three parts mad with terror, that man's name is Pinner. What can have put the shivers on him.
Is Holmes referring by "three parts" to himself, Watson and Pycroft being the reason of Pinner's terror or something else and what does Pinner's name have to do with his being or not being afraid ?

Comment: Holmes is referring to Pinner. 'Three parts' could be taken to mean 'three-quarters', that is, *mostly*. It could be that Pinner is three parts mad with terror, and only one quarter tempered by reason. The implication is that if a terrified man is seen, he is most likely to be Pinner.

Comment: How about "That man's name is Pinner" what do you make of it ?

Comment: As edited into the previous comment: if it is known that Pinner is terrified, and an unidentified man is seen who is terrified, that man is probably Pinner.

Comment: Thank you Weather Vane

Comment: It's a figure of speech with the sense "If it's possible for a man to be three-quarters mad with terror, that's what Pinner was".